# How to trigger to load after appending the script

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am working with CKEditor and this editor creates a new DOM tree at variable - editor.document.$. I have appended JS scripts to editor.document.$.head, but I don't understand how i can trigger them to actually load:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
    editor = ev.editor;
    if(editor.name == 'edit-body-und-0-value'){
     var head = editor.document.getHead();
     var body = editor.document.getBody();

     var s0 = editor.document.$.createElement( 'script' );
     s0.type = 'text/javascript';
     s0.onload = function() {
         console.log( 'script path/jquery-1.11.0.min.js loaded' );
     };
     s0.src = '/path/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
     s0.$ = s0;
     head.append(s0);

     var s2 = editor.document.$.createElement( 'script' );
     s2.type = 'text/javascript';
     s2.onload = function() {
         console.log( 'script path/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js loaded' );
     };
     s2.src = '/path/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js';
     s2.$ = s2;
     head.append(s2);

     jQuery(editor.document.$).ready(function($) {
         $ = jQuery(editor.document.$);
         $.trigger("load");
         Some.init();
         Layout.init();
         ...
      });
    }
});
```

I can see the scripts appended to the head, however, none of them are loaded. They got loaded somehow later but its too late. I want them be loaded before the "init" is called. How to do that? Thank You